# How to upload files to Google Docs through Google Data API?

Tags: python, google-api

I developing an application which works with Google API, according to my understanding.

```
def push_to_ga(request):
    client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
    client.ClientLogin('account@gmail.com', 'password')

    entrys = Entry.objects.all()
    for entry in entrys:
        splitted = entry.file.split('/')
        client.UploadDocument(entry.file, splitted[-1])

    return HttpResponseRedirect('https://docs.google.com/#home')
```

Have an error:

> Traceback:
>   File "/home/i159/Env/googleapi/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/home/i159/workspace/apiroot/googleapi/../googleapi/apiapp/views.py" in push_to_ga
>     38.         client.UploadDocument(entry.file, 'My entry #' + str(entry.id))
>   File "/home/i159/Env/googleapi/lib/python2.6/site-packages/atom/**init**.py" in deprecated_function
>     1475.       return f(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/i159/Env/googleapi/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata/docs/service.py" in UploadDocument
>     494.         folder_or_uri=folder_or_uri)
>   File "/home/i159/Env/googleapi/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata/docs/service.py" in _UploadFile
>     160.                       extra_headers={'Slug': media_source.file_name},
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /push_to_ga/
>   Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'file_name'

I can't find docs with description of the methods. How to upload file into Google Docs through API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the Google API are you using?

According to the [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#UploadingDocs), for versions 1.0 and 2.0 you have to wrap the document as a [MediaSource](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.html#MediaSource) object in order to pass it to the Upload method. So, I think you need to replace:

```
client.UploadDocument(entry.file, splitted[-1])
```

with:

```
ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_path=entry.file, content_type=gdata.docs.service.SUPPORTED_FILETYPES['DOC'])
client.Upload(ms, splitted[-1])
```

Note: this assumes that you are uploading Word files. You should set the `content_type` parameter to the [correct type](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/faq.html#WhatKindOfFilesCanIUpload) for each file that you upload.

If you're using [version 3.0](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#UploadingDocs), you no longer need to create a MediaSource object - you can simply pass the pathname, title and mime type directly to the Upload method:

```
client.Upload(entry.file, splitted[-1], content_type='application/msword')
```

**Uploading PDFs**

If you attempt to upload PDF files using version 2.0 of the API, it fails with the error:

```
{'status': 415, 'body': 'Content-Type application/pdf is not a valid input type.', 'reason': 'Unsupported Media Type'}
```

This can be fixed using the workaround shown in [comment 77](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=591#c77) on issue 591 on the Google Code site. Simple edit the `_UploadFile` method in your `site-packages/gdata/docs/services.py` file as shown on that ticket. Once you have made this change, PDF uploads should work fine (I have checked this & it works for me).

Comment: @I159 I saw your comment about PDF files and have updated my answer accordingly.